# Did Muhammad al-Arifi describe non-Arab Muslims as cowards?

Tags: quotes, islam

The following photo was posted in the *[Citizens for secular democracy, Pakistan](https://web.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1821116231491258&set=gm.1331089940285580&type=3&permPage=1)* Facebook group.

> [image]

It claims Saudi author [Muhammad al-Arifi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohamad_al-Arefe) said:

> ARABS are the true Muslims
>   and the true descendants of
>   Prophet Muhammad (pbuh)..
>
> "Non—Arabs who without shame, called themselves Muslims are just plain Converts whom are lowly cowards with unhonourable souls That were overwhelmed with ease by the Swords of Allah, thus they deserved to be called as our Dogs."

The authenticity of the quote is disputed in this [Reddit/Islam](https://www.reddit.com/r/islam/comments/3j36me/i_came_across_this_image_on_twitter_who_is_this/) post.

> I came across this image on twitter. Who is this man ? Is there any relevance in what he is saying ? Thanks in advance.

The second comment to the R/Islam post says:

> I genuinely doubt he said this.

Is this quote authentic?

Comment: And this twitter makes it look like it is from 30 August 2015 or before https://twitter.com/amisri/status/638167456414986241

Comment: Re "...the true descendants of Prophet Muhammad...", doesn't that rather glaringly ignore the fact that few (if any) of Muhammad's children were numbered among the original Muslims?  And that the majority of Arabs were likewise "overwhelmed with ease by the Swords of Allah"?  (Though the "with ease" part is arguable.)  Or indeed, that one could apply the very same argument, in reverse, to Israel and the Arab world :-)

Comment: It might improve the question if you a) added a brief explanation of just who Muhammad al-Arifi is; and b) clarify whether you're asking about the statement, or whether the statement was made by this particular person?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohamad_al-Arefe

Comment: @DavePhD: And I thought this site really disapproved of using Wikipedia as an answer.

Comment: @jamesqf: It is widely used here to provide context by defining uncontroversial terms that might not be familiar to all readers.  That's how it is being used in this question. It is also sometimes used in questions as evidence of notability.

Comment: I am muslim and self claims and self praises is prohibited in Islam and the quote isn't anywhere in Quran nor who is descendant of Prophet Muhammad as all sect says they are nearer or from there bloodline.But claims are nothing, nor Quran mentions any.

Comment: @Nofel Salam. The question is about whether he said it or not. I am being skeptical of the photos authenticity. It sounded like a false accusation against al-Arifi so I asked whether he said it or not.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin wsalam, no doubt that menace people do these kind of things, the only way to authenticate is find a lecture, where he said this. anyone can photoshop and put something on it as a mischief.

Comment: Dr. Muhammad Al-'Arifi is known to have said in an interview that "women in the West Marry Dogs and Donkeys"-https://www.memri.org/tv/saudi-author-dr-muhammad-al-arifi-show-produced-saudi-ministry-religious-endowments-women-west.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin - You mischaracterized that article. It says that Memri presents a biased selection of articles, and sometimes omits important context or even describes independent newspapers as government-affiliated, but that, to the knowledge of the author, there's never been a demonstrated maliciously false translation (though there could be, of course).